# Merge GraphQL Types and their arguments in a stitched schema

Tags: graphql, postgraphile

I have two GraphQL schemas that define two different Types `User` which are in a one-to-one relationship. Each of them implements a set of arguments (`filter`, `condition`, ...) that are used for filtering for example.

```js
// analyticsSchema
type User {
  id: String!
  actions: Int
}

// metadataSchema
type User {
  id: String!
  age: Int
}
```

These types are merged bi-directionally:

```js
const gatewaySchema = stitchSchemas({
  subschemas: [
    {
      schema: analyticsSchema,
      merge: {
        User: {
          fieldName: 'analyticsById',
          selectionSet: '{ id }',
          args: originalObject => ({ id: originalObject.id }),
        },
      },
    },
    {
      schema: metadataSchema,
      merge: {
        User: {
          fieldName: 'metadataById',
          selectionSet: '{ id }',
          args: originalObject => ({ id: originalObject.id }),
        },
      },
    },
  ],
  mergeTypes: true, 
});
```

With this implementation, I do not have access to all fields for filtering:

```js
// What I can do 
query ExampleQuery {
  allUsers(filter: { actions: { greaterThan: 10 }}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        actions
        age
      }
    }
  }
}

// What I would like to do
query ExampleQuery {
  allUsers(filter: {actions: {greaterThan: 10}, age: {lessThan: 35}}) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        actions
        age
      }
    }
  }
}

> Problem: Field "age" is not defined by type "UserFilter".
```

My question is, is it possible to expose all filtering arguments to the resulting merged type? Or maybe I'm going the wrong way?

N.B: both GraphQL endpoints rely on `postgraphile` and we're using the `postgraphile-plugin-connection-filter` plugin if that matters.

Comment: Did you try delegating request from one query to another? Is there any issue with using a single Schema for both `Users` and initialize non-used datatype will `'NULL` value?